# python german umlaut issues - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

I am reading from csv file and saving data into my model.

```
with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\f.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        uname =  u"'" + row[2]+"'".encode('utf-8')
        u = University(name=uname)
        u.save()
```

and i have a word in file: `Westfälisch`. this is the word where the code gets stuck.

this is error message:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: Westf�lisch
```

what am i doing wrong? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uname =  ("'" + row[2]+"'").decode('utf-8') # Just that you need
```

Comment: @doniyor: If your original data is in Latin-1 rather than UTF-8, then yes, of course you need `decode('latin-1')`. But your question very strongly implied that it was UTF-8, so you can't blame shhdup for assuming it!

Comment: of course, i didnot know that it was latin-1. i never blame shhdup, very appreciated his help at 00.55 oclock :)

Answer (score 7):

shhdup's answer shows how to do this correctly, but doesn't explain what you're doing wrong.

---

The actual reason you're getting the error is that you're adding `u"'"`, which is a `unicode` object, and `row[2]`, which is a `str` object. Concatenating a `unicode` and a `str` (in either order) automatically decodes the `str` using `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is almost always `'ascii'`.

There are two reasons for this problem. First, this:

```
u"'" + row[2]+"'".encode('utf-8')
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
u"'" + row[2] + ("'".encode('utf-8'))
```

… rather than:

```
(u"'" + row[2] + "'").encode('utf-8')
```

However, even if you fix that, you're still adding Unicode and bytes strings together inside the parens. So you either want this:

```
u"'" + row[2].encode('utf-8') + u"'"
```

… or

```
("'" + row[2] + "'").encode('utf-8')
```

---

You're also using `encode` instead of `decode`.

And you're `'utf-8'` instead of `'Latin-1'` even though your data is Latin-1.

But your code isn't getting far enough for either of those to matter. And neither one of those problems will give you the error you're getting.